# Pinterest oauth issue - Why does pinterest popup auth not closing?

Tags: meteor, authentication, oauth, pinterest, accounts

Steps :

1. Meteor add semencovroman34:accounts-pinterest
2. Create app on developers.pinterest.com
3. Configure Service configuration
4. deploy app to yourapp.meteor.com
5. in developers.pinterest.com set redirect link to yourapp.meteor.com/_oauth/pinterest?close
6. Use Meteor.loginWithPinterest() to try login

Issue: i tried to do package for pinterest login, based on  other packages, but it isn't work.

When i click on [OK button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yOWv.jpg) , it is redirect to next page
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPweG.jpg) and all - it will same
when i use redirect type login - account not registered.

[link for code on github](https://github.com/Tobe3/accounts-pinterest)

Help,please.

Comment: Does browser console show something meaningful right after you click "OK" button? A warning or an error, maybe? And does the server console show any errors?

Comment: No errors, no error from server console, nothing

Comment: please show the code of the according "Result" page yourapp.meteor.com/_oauth/pinterest?close

Comment: @AxelAmthorit ,turned out that there is an error
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxxx.meteor.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://xxxxx.meteor.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.